# Ranger/druid spells per day vs. spells known

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, ranger

The spells per day is in the chart for the class. The caster level is easy to figure out. But how many spells do I know? The same numbers as are in the chart? I though I read that I gained two spells per level but the chart doesn't show this.

Answer (score 15):

They can cast any spells on the appropriate spell list, they do not have a specific number of spells known.

[Ranger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger)

> A ranger may prepare and cast any spell on the ranger spell list, provided that he can cast spells of that level, but he must choose which spells to prepare during his daily meditation.

[Druid](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid)

> A druid may prepare and cast any spell on the druid spell list, provided that she can cast spells of that level, but she must choose which spells to prepare during her daily meditation.

Where you probably read about gaining 2 spells known per level was probably in the description of the Wizard.